# ifelse Vs Map? [C++]

Tags: c++, if-statement, c++17, stdmap, std-function

- I have a class that receives `key` and `value` parameters from other classes.
- Both `key` and `value` are `std::string`.
- Right now the function `setParameter` uses a chained if-else if -else if - else logic:

```
void setParamater(std::string key, std::string value){
    if(key == KEYPARAM_1)
    {
       //Do something
    }
    else if(key == KEYPARAM_2)
    {
       //Do something
    }
    else if (key == KEYPARAM_3)
    {
       //Do something
    }
    else if (key == KEYPARAM_4)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    else if (key == KEYPARAM_5)
    {
       //Do something
    }
    else if (key == KEYPARAM_6) {
       //Do something
    }
    else
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

- I find this very ugly and its a code that makes many unnecasary comparisons (the more parameters the more comparions).
- I had the idea of doing a `map` of string and functinos: `std::map<std::string; std::funtion<std::string>>` to replace this code.
- The first `std::string` would be the key, the `std::function`would replace the code in the `//Do something` lines and the other `std::string` would be the value.
- The negative part of this solution is that I would be creating an object for each `key` and I would have to find a nice place to declare all the functions. The good thing is that is easy to call and wont do all the ifelse comparisons. Somehing like this would be kind of pretty:

```
void setParamater(std::string key, std::string value){
      my_map(key, f(value)); //I'm not sure about the syntax in there
}
```

- Does someone have a better idea to replace the if-else chain? Is the `map` a good idea?

-FYI: each case does something quite different is not just a setters.

Thank you!

Comment: Another possibility is to use a map, to associate each `KEYPARAM_X` to an integer, and then to use this integer to perform a switch statement `switch (MyMAp[key]) { ...`

Comment: Are you using `value` at all? It's not clear what its purpose is.

Comment: The best option would be to use map, unordered_map or set, as you've guessed. If-else statements are neither scalable, nor maintainable.

Comment: @Damien: That would be a double lookup. The switch does not provide a benefit.

Comment: @MSalters The benefit would be a clear code, rather easy to maintain. I have used this solution from time to time. When you are speaking of benefit, are you considering efficiency? I did not understand it was OP concern, but i may be wrong.

Comment: @Damien: You need to maintain a map and a switch. That's less efficient than just a single map, both in terms of CPU and developer-hours.

Comment: @cigien the `value` is used in different ways for each `key`, sorry I can see why i wasnt clear

Comment: @Damien efficiency efficiency is a concern!

Comment: @MSalters efficiency efficiency is a concern!

Comment: In general, each of those `//Do something`s can often be a function call. If you change all of them to function calls you can change the control structure much more easily, from that `if ... else if...` ladder to some kind of lookup, for example. But there's nothing inherently bad about an `if ... else if ...` ladder. It's appropriateness depends on how many branches it has and  how often you have to add or remove branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to declare a function for `std::function`. The alternative is to use a lambda. That lambda can go straight into your map initialization.

It would look something like

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void(std::string)> funcs {
   std::make_pair(KEYPARAM_1, [](std::string s) { std::cout << s; },
   std::make_pair(KEYPARAM_2, [](std::string s) { /* something else */ }
}
```

Comment: Could you replace the void input for a string and, please, show how to call a function? :) and i'll mark it as the answer

Comment: @Ivan: That's easy.